# Python3, Beautifulsoup4 tag confusion

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

i'm trying to get some data from amazon my code is:

```
import requests, bs4

source_code = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_keywords_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A%212335753011%2Cn%3A7072561011%2Cn%3A2407749011%2Cp_89%3AHuawei%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_four_browse-bin%3A6787346011&bbn=2407749011&ie=UTF8&qid=1473923594&rnid=6787345011", 
    headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
})
source_code.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, 'lxml')
mobile_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="a-row a-spacing-small")
for mobile_name in mobile_div:
    print(mobile_name.a.find_next("h2").string)
```

it outputs fine but when i use

```
print(mobile_name.a.h2.string)
```

instead of that it shows the following error:

```
print(mobile_name.a.h2.string)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

My markup is :
[image]

Can anyone explain why i'm getting this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the first anchor returned is:

```
<a class="a-button-text" href="/gp/help/contact-us/general-questions.html/ref=sr_hms_cs/155-8370713-5732665?browse_node_id=468556&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1473939395" role="button">contact us</a>
```

It has no *h2* child/descendant, calling *find_next* looks everywhere after that anchor for a *h2* so even if it does not have a child it will find the next one. `a.h2` looks for a child/descendant of the anchor so for the first anchor above returns None.

[*find_all_next() and find_next()*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next)

*These methods use .next_elements to iterate over **whatever tags and strings that come after it in the document**. The find_all_next() method returns all matches, and find_next() only returns the first match:*

This simple example should

```
In [34]: html = """<div>
          <a class="a-button-text" href="/fof.com">foobar</a> 
          <h2 class="sibling"> blah</h2> 
          <div ><h2 class="nexted"> blah</h2></div> 
          </div>"""

In [34]: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

In [35]: a = soup.div.a
In [36]: print(a.h2) # a has no direct descendants so we get None
None
In [37]: a.find_next("h2") # finds the next h2 anywhere after the anchor 
Out[37]: <h2 class="sibling"> blah</h2>


In [38]: a.find_next_siblings("h2") # finds any h2's in the tree that are siblings
Out[38]: [<h2 class="sibling"> blah</h2>]

In [39]: a.find_all_next("h2") # finds all h2s anywhere after 
Out[39]: [<h2 class="sibling"> blah</h2>, <h2 class="nexted"> blah</h2>]
```